# Comparison of reshape functions

Tags: r, reshape

What are the differences between the multiple reshape functions? Which is the best and when to use which?

| package | first release date | current version | latest release date | wide → long | long → wide |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stats |  | 4.3.0 |  | reshape | reshape |
| reshape | 2005-08-05 | 0.8.9 | 2022-04-12 | melt | cast |
| reshape2 | 2010-09-10 | 1.4.4 | 2020-04-09 | melt | dcast / acast |
| tidyr | 2014-07-21 | 1.2.0 | 2022-02-01 | gather | spread |
| tidyr | 2014-07-21 | 1.2.0 | 2022-02-01 | pivot_longer | pivot_wider |
| tidyverse | 2016-09-09 | 1.3.1 | 2021-04-15 |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

### Further information

[Nguyen, Hai. (2022-06-22). The Evolution of Reshaping Data: stats — tidyr](https://rpubs.com/Haibiostat/reshapedata)

Comment: From the article the reshape2 package is obsolete and gather from tidyr is retired in favor of pivot_longer. Tidyverse is just a wrapper for tidyr.  That shortens the list. So the question  is stick with base R or use a package?  Overall pivot_longer is more powerful and seems more popular.

Comment: @Dave2e I'm a bit unsure, if the information on the website is correct as it states "`reshape` (2005-2010)" and "`reshape2` (2010-2014)". Also `spreadsheet` and `database` are mentioned, but I'm unsure what is meant by this. I can't find packages with such names

Comment: Also, maybe there are further packages which are not listed?